# Calculus of Angular and Linear Velocity

Tags: calculus

I have a question regarding the following forms in the case that both angular velocity and radius change per $dt$.  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity) defines angular velocity in two dimensions as:

$$
\omega = \frac {d \phi} {dt}
$$

then linear velocity $v$ as:

$$
\mathcal{l} = r \phi, v(t) = \frac {d \mathcal{l}}{d t} = r \omega(t)
$$

What is the equation for linear velocity if both $r$ and $\theta$ change per $dt$?  Is $r$ parametrized to $r(t)$?  I'm confused because $r$ is a constant in the above forms, where I would expect it to be part of the change $d \mathcal{l}$.

Comment: What is "time quantum"?

Comment: it is $dt$.....

Comment: Yes, you would write $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ if both depend on an independent (and common) time variable.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(x(t),y(t))=(r(t)\cos \theta(t),r(t) \sin\theta(t)).$$ Then
\begin{align}
|\mathbf{v}(t)|^2&=(x')^2+(y')^2\\
&=(r'\cos \theta-r(\sin \theta) \theta')^2+(r'\sin \theta+ r(\cos \theta) \theta')\\
&=(r')^2+r^2(\theta')^2\\
&=(\frac{dr}{dt})^2+r^2\omega^2.
\end{align}
So
$$
|\mathbf{v}(t)|=\sqrt{(\frac{dr}{dt})^2+r^2\omega^2}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

It explains in that Wikipedia article that for a general case of a point moving in the plane (so not specifically with a fixed distance from the origin), that the derivative of its position vector $\mathbf{r}$ with respect to $t$ (i.e. its velocity vector) is given by

$$\frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt} = \dot{r} \hat{\mathbf{r}} + r \dot{\varphi}\hat{\varphi}$$

The linear speed is the magnitude of the velocity vector, so

$$\begin{eqnarray} \frac{dl}{dt} & = & \left | \frac{d \mathbf{r}}{dt} \right | \\
& = & \left| \dot{r} \hat{r} + r \dot{\varphi}\hat{\varphi} \right | \\
& = & \sqrt{|\dot{r} \hat{r}|^2 + |r \dot{\varphi}\hat{\varphi}|^2} & \text{since } \hat{r} \text{ and } \hat{\varphi} \text{ are orthogonal} \\
 & = & \sqrt{\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\varphi}^2} & \text{since } \hat{r} \text{ and } \hat{\varphi} \text{ are unit vectors}
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Regarding your first mention of the Wiki form $\frac{d\mathbf{r}}{dt} = (\dot{r}\cos(\varphi) - r\dot{\varphi}\sin(\varphi), \dot{r}\sin(\varphi) + r\dot{\varphi}\cos(\varphi))$.  Do you know how the derivative for this form was arrived at?  I don't see $t$ anywhere in the equation for which to substitute for.

Comment: All of the dots represent a derivative with respect to $t$, so $\dot{r} = \frac{dr}{dt}$. You can derive the expression either by working from the representation $\mathbf{r} = (x, y) = (r \cos \varphi, r \sin \varphi)$ and differentiating each component with respect to $t$ before recombining into a vector form, or else you can apply the [multivariate chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case).